# rdflib.js Load data into the store from a buffer/string

Tags: javascript, rdf, owl, rdflib

I want to load an owl.file with rdflib.js based on this [tutorial](https://github.com/solid/solid-tutorial-rdflib.js) but get the following error:

*Error: Error: NamedNode IRI "/ontologies/opcua.owl" must be absolute. while trying to parse </ontologies/opcua.owl> as application/rdf+xml*

I "installed" rdflib.js to use in the Browser (with generating a "script" file)
**Excerpt of the HTML-File**

```html
<script src="rdflib.js/dist/rdflib.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/OWL.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Code**

```js
const store = $rdf.graph();

var uri = ('/ontologies/opcua.owl').toString();
var mimeType = 'application/rdf+xml';

var body

try {
    $rdf.parse(body, store, uri, mimeType)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Thanks in advance for every hint or remarks to my code.

Comment: the error message is quite clear to me, you must provide a full path URI or not? did you try this?

Comment: @UninformedUser changed my example path to a full path as you suggested (http://127.0.0.1:5500/ontologies/opcua.owl) but received the following error. 

Error: Error: RDF/XML syntax error: No namespace for style in http://127.0.0.1:5500/ontologies/opcua.owl while trying to parse <http://127.0.0.1:5500/ontologies/opcua.owl> as application/rdf+xml
    at b (parse.ts:103:18)
    at Module.d (parse.ts:67:5)
    at OWL.js:10:10

This is due to the rdf tag in the file if i understand this correctly?

Comment: Please un-tag this question with `rdflib` as that's the tag for the Python toolkit, not `rdflib.js`